# 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<options>'

Tags: flutter

I am getting error as `'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<options>'`

Here is my code:

```dart
List<SampleModel> cartList = allStores.keys
  // var allStores = response.data['data'];
  // var cartList = allStores.keys
  .map((name) => SampleModel(
    sname: name,
    selected: false,
    storeList: allStores[name].map((name) => SampleModel(
      sname: name,
      selected: false,
      storeList: allStores[name].map<Store>((store) => Store(
        id: store['id'],
        selected: false,
        stid: store['stid'],
        product: Products(
          id: store['product']['id'],
          type: store['product']['type_id'],
          options:  store['product']['options'].length > 0 ? store['product']['options'].map((f) => Options.fromJson(f)).toList() : null
        ),
                             
      )
    ).toList(),
  )
).toList();
```

Model:

```dart
class SampleModel {
  String sname;
  bool selected;
  List<Store> storeList;
    
  SampleModel({this.sname, this.selected, this.storeList});
    
  SampleModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    sname = json['sname'];
    selected = json['selected'];
    storeList = List<Store>.from(json["storeList"].map((x) => Store.fromJson(x)));
  }
      
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['sname'] = this.sname;
    data['selected'] = this.selected;
    data['storeList'] = List<dynamic>.from(storeList.map((x) => x.toJson()));
    return data;
  }
}
    
class Store {
  int id;
  int stid;
     
    
  Store({
    this.id,
    this.stid,
  });
    
  Store.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    stid = json['cart_id'];
    selected = json['selected'];
    quantity = json['quantity'];
     
    product = Products.fromJson(json["product"]);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['cart_id'] = this.stid;
    
    data['product'] = product.toJson();
    
    return data;
  }
}
    
class Products {
  int id;
  String name;
  List<Options> options;
    
  Products({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.options,
  });
    
  Products.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
    type = json['type'];
    
    options = json["options"] == null
     ? null
     : List<Options>.from(
       json["options"].map((x) => Options.fromJson(x)));
     }
    
    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
      final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
      data['id'] = this.id;
      data['name'] = this.name;
    
      data['options'] = options == null
       ? null
       : List<dynamic>.from(options.map((x) => x.toJson()));
      return data;
    }
  }
}
    
class Options {
  int id;
  String name;
    
  Options({
    this.id,
    this.name,
  });
    
  Options.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    name = json['name'];
  }
    
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    
    return data;
  }
}
```

Here is my sample json

```json
{
  "sta1": [{
    "id": 948,
    "sid": 67,
    "product": {
      "id": 123,
      "name": "tesssss",
      "Options": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "asdasd"
      }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "wer",
        "seq": 1
      }]
    }
  }],
  "sta2": [{
    "id": 948,
    "sid": 67,
    "product": {
      "id": 123,
      "name": "tesssss",
      "Options": [{
        "id": 1,
        "name": "asdasd"
      }, {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "wer",
        "seq": 1
      }]
    }
  }]
}
```

Everything works fine but options is not mapping, it shows error as

**'List' is not a subtype of type 'List'**

What am I missing here? Its an object and options is an array so I need to have it as a list in front end
everything i can able to loop but one thing options is not working

getting error in following line

```
   options:  store['product']['options'].length > 0 ? store['product']['options'].map((f) => Options.fromJson(f)).toList() : null
```

Comment: Can you add the line where you get exception to the question?

Comment: updarted.......

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I think that Flutter lost the reference of type of object, but I can fix using like this in your `fromJson`:

```
options = json["options"] == null
     ? null
     : List<Options>.from(
       json["options"].map<Option>((x) => Options.fromJson(x.cast<String, dynamic>())));
     }
```

Casting the map and using the cast in your map object.
I hope that can help you too.

Comment: Can you say if your error is in fromJson or toJson ?